# Cannot read config file .eslintrc.json Error: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, json, eslint

I'm exploring EsLint for my React JS ES6 project and I'm immediately stuck.
I've created an **.eslintrc.json** exactly like [here](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options):

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": 2
    }
}
```

What do I do now?

```
Cannot read config file: /Users/eric/af/frontend_app/.eslintrc.json
Error: Unexpected token }
SyntaxError: Cannot read config file: /Users/eric/af/frontend_app/.eslintrc.json
Error: Unexpected token }
    at Object.parse (native)
    at loadJSONConfigFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:117:21)
    at loadConfigFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:210:26)
    at Object.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:437:18)
    at loadConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:67:33)
    at getLocalConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:129:23)
    at Config.getConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:223:22)
    at processText (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:155:27)
    at processFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:227:18)
    at executeOnFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:603:23)
```

My EsLint version:

```
$ eslint -v
v2.4.0
```

I've tried changing the name of the same config file to **.eslintrc.js** and I've got this:

```
Cannot read config file: /Users/eric/af/frontend_app/.eslintrc.js
Error: /Users/eric/af/frontend_app/.eslintrc.js:2
    "parserOptions": {
                   ^
Unexpected token :
/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/.eslintrc.js:2
    "parserOptions": {
                   ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/require-uncached/index.js:14:12)
    at loadJSConfigFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:157:16)
    at loadConfigFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:197:22)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this ( I removed the comma after `"ecmaFeatures": {"jsx": true},`):

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": 2
    }
}
```

Use this tool to valid your json : http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: thanks a lot, so this is really an invalid JSON script, their documentation really wows me here